# Amazon S3 - accessing bucket from nodejs SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I ran into problems accessing my brand new bucket (created via aws console) from nodejs with the node SDK. Steps I made (please help if I missed something)

- Created an aws account so I have now a root user
- Created a new access key for the SDK
- Went to S3 and created a new bucket withhin the console
- In nodejs I try to upload something to this bucket but I keep getting 'Access Denied' w/o further explanation.

I tried different regions with the buckets as well as generating new access keys and also trying to set up lower permissions for the buckets to the point where I enable everything for everyone with one of the test buckets but still getting the error.

The code bits:

```
    class SomeNodeService {

        constructor() {
            this.s3 = new S3({
                params: {
                    Bucket: 'some.bucket.which.name.is.unique',
                    accessKeyId: 'SOMEID',
                    secretAccessKey: 'SOMEID'
                }
            });
        }

        uploadAttachment(attachment) {
            const _this = this;
            return co(function * () {
                const file = yield _readFile(attachment.path, 'utf8');
                const key = `${KEY_PREFIX}attachment/${Date.now()}/${attachment.name}`;
                const params = {
                    Key: key,
                    Body: file
                };

                return yield _this.s3.putObject(params).promise();
            });
        }

    }
```

I don't know what I am missing :S

---

As per @filipebarretto I created a new user, and created new access tokens for that user and also gave him AmazonS3FullAccess. Worth to mention that I also created a group name 'sysadmin' and I provided the AmazonS3FullAccess permission to the group itself, so assigning the user to the group resulted in granting the permission to the user too. So all in all what I did

1) create new group sysadm 2) grant group permission "AmazonS3FullAccess" 3) create new user XY and join group sysadm 4) recreate access tokens for XY user

But I still get Access Denied :/

Comment: The credentials you are using are associated with the root user? Or a different user with other permissions?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with AWS yet, although I created a user and provided the S3 IAM role to him, but for me it seems that the access tokens are only bound to the root account/root user not to any subsequent users.

Comment: Could you please add the policy you provided in the question?
When you create a user, you can create credentials for him. You should never have credentials on your account root.

Comment: @filipebarretto I edited the original question

Answer (score 1):

To configure your credentials, you and use:

```
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "accessKey";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "secretKey";
AWS.config.region = "region";
```

This is not the best neither the safest way to do so. For more information, check: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html

You should define the Bucket and the Key in the params, such as:

```
const params = {
    Key: key,
    Body: file
};

return yield _this.s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

On your constructor, use only:

```
constructor() {
    this.s3 = new S3();
}
```

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: Same issue, this did not help unfortunately :( But thanks anyways.

Comment: @Jim-Y I complemented the answer. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks, sadly this couldn't be the source of the problem because in other parts of the application we use AWS for other things too, like AWS-SES for emailing where the API is kinda' the same and we provide the credentials like I did in my question. Read the creds from environment variables and provide them as params to the SES/S3 constructor.